# workbooks.open error calling VBA code in xlsm file

Tags: python, vba

I have VBA code in an .xlsm file that I would like to run. VBA code works good (I have checked multiple times running from Excel itself). Here is my python code that calls the VBA code.

```
import os, os.path
import win32com.client

# sap COPYING

if os.path.exists("sapdownload.xlsm"):
    xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath("sapdownload.xlsm"), ReadOnly=1)
    xl.Application.Run("sapdownload.xlsm!module3.copying1")
    xl.Application.Quit() # Comment this out if your excel script closes
    del xl

# Sap DOWNLOADINFIG reports
if os.path.exists("sapdownload.xlsm"):
    xl2=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl2.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath("sapdownload.xlsm"),ReadOnly=1)
    xl2.Application.Run("sapdownload.xlsm!module2.SAPDownloadAttachment")
    xl2.Application.Quit() # Comment this out if your excel script closes
    del xl2
```

The above code is in `Generate.py` file that user is calling from tkinter window by clicking the button. First part runs without problem but second one has a problem at line. Note that if I run this from interpreter it runs and I get desired output. Only when I run it from tkinter window it gives me the error on this line:

```
xl2.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath("sapdownload.xlsm"))
```

Error:

```
raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
  AttributeError: Excel.Application.Workbooks
```

Not sure where I make mistake.

Comment: Have you checked what `os.path.abspath("sapdownload.xlsm")` is actually returning when you get the error?

Comment: sorry, Im beginner and have hard time to understand what are u refereeing to. Could you please elaborate it?

Comment: Why not just add the second `Run` command to the first code block, after `xl.Application.Run("sapdownload.xlsm!module3.copying1")`?  Why open the same workbook a second time?

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks it worked well, only thing is that small excel window pop us and asking me to save changes. Is it possible to ignore this pop op and save it automatically? I think I have to remove `ReadOnly=1`

Comment: Try explicitly closing the workbook before you quit Excel - `xl2.Workbooks("sapdownload.xlsm").Close(SaveChanges=False)`